# Group JSON as new objects based on data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have some JSON data that stores a date time string and total. e.g.

```
[{
    "Date": "2012-04-01 12:00:00",
    "Total": "14"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-02 06:00:00",
    "Total": "3"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-02 14:00:00",
    "Total": "12"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-02 16:00:00",
    "Total": "5"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-02 17:00:00",
    "Total": "7"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-03 06:00:00",
    "Total": "9"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-03 14:00:00",
    "Total": "2"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-04 06:00:00",
    "Total": "1"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-04 14:00:00",
    "Total": "10"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-04 19:00:00",
    "Total": "8"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-04 21:00:00",
    "Total": "4"
}]
```

What I'd like to do is create new JSON objects for data that is the same year, month, and day.

So for example a full set of data could be formatted into:

DAY:

```
[{
    "Date": "2012-04-01"
    "Total": "3"
},{
    "Date": "2012-04-02"
    "Total": "4"
},{
    "Date": "2012-04-03"
    "Total": "6"
}]
```

MONTH:

```
[{
    "Date": "2012-04"
    "Total": "36"
},{
    "Date": "2012-05"
    "Total": "11"
},{
    "Date": "2012-06"
    "Total": "23"
},{
    "Date": "2012-07"
    "Total": "17"
}]
```

YEAR:

```
[{
    "Date": "2012"
    "Total": "91"
},{
    "Date": "2013"
    "Total": "102"
},{
    "Date": "2014"
    "Total": "78"
}]
```

How could I do this is Rails? **If I could get an example of how I could do one of them, then I could then use that as a base to do the others!**

So in the controller I have:

```
def get_count_day
    render json: data.to_json
end

def get_count_month
    render json: data.to_json
end

def get_count_year
    render json: data.to_json
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can try this way for Day

```
given_json.group_by{|b| b["Date"].to_date.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")}.collect{|key,value| {"Date" =>key , "Total" => value.sum{|d| d["Total"].to_i}}}
```

For Month

```
given_json.group_by{|b| b["Date"].to_date.strftime("%Y-%m")}.collect{|key,value| {"Date" =>key , "Total" => value.sum{|d| d["Total"].to_i}}}
```

For Year

```
given_json.group_by{|b| b["Date"].to_date.strftime("%Y")}.collect{|key,value| {"Date" =>key , "Total" => value.sum{|d| d["Total"].to_i}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
count_by_day = 
  json.group_by{ |record| record[:Date].to_date.strftime }
      .map { |k, v| { Date: k, Total: v.map { |y| y[:Total].to_i }.sum.to_s } }

#=> [{:Date=>"2012-04-01", :Total=>"14"}, {:Date=>"2012-04-02", :Total=>"27"}, {:Date=>"2012-04-03", :Total=>"11"}, {:Date=>"2012-04-04", :Total=>"23"}]

count_by_month = 
  json.group_by{ |record| record[:Date].to_date.strftime('%Y-%m') }
      .map { |k, v| { Date: k, Total: v.map { |y| y[:Total].to_i }.sum.to_s } }

#=> [{:Date=>"2012-04", :Total=>"75"}]

count_by_year = 
  json.group_by{ |record| record[:Date].to_date.strftime('%Y') }
      .map { |k, v| { Date: k, Total: v.map { |y| y[:Total].to_i }.sum.to_s } }

#=> [{:Date=>"2012", :Total=>"75"}]
```

Comment: `json` here is the array of hashes you have posted in the question

Comment: in your case, I think it will be `data.group_by....` if `data` is `{
    "Date": "2012-04-01 12:00:00",
    "Total": "14"
}, {
    "Date": "2012-04-02 06:00:00",
    "Total": "3"
}.....]`

Comment: I'm currently pulling the JSON from a CSV like: `json = CSV.open(Rails.public_path + 'testData.csv', :headers => true).map { |x| x.to_h }.to_json` so it should be JSON as posted.

Comment: then it should work on `json` itself . I have tried it on your posted data it  must work if the data is in that format,

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to retrieve them grouped by day:

```
grouped_json = Hash.new(0)
your_json_array.each do |array_element|
  date = Date.parse(array_element['Date']).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  grouped_json[date] += array_element['Total']
end
grouped_json.map {|k,v| {'Date' => k, 'Total' => v} }
```

by month?

```
grouped_json = Hash.new(0)
your_json_array.each do |array_element|
  date = Date.parse(array_element['Date']).strftime('%Y-%m')
  grouped_json[date] += array_element['Total']
end
grouped_json.map {|k,v| {'Date' => k, 'Total' => v} }
```

by year?

```
grouped_json = Hash.new(0)
your_json_array.each do |array_element|
  date = Date.parse(array_element['Date']).strftime('%Y')
  grouped_json[date] += array_element['Total']
end
grouped_json.map {|k,v| {'Date' => k, 'Total' => v} }
```